# How to notify the system setting changed in Android

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, android-settings

I develop an app (push to /system/app)and want to modify some system settings, I do like the

```
 public void changeAnimationSettings(boolean isChecked) {

        int result1 = isChecked ? 0 : 1;
        Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, result1);
        Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, result1);
        Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE, result1);


        Log.i(TAG, "---->>ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE: " + Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE));
        Log.i(TAG, "---->>WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE: " + Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE));
        Log.i(TAG, "---->>TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE " + Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE));

    }
```

the log show the value has changed successful, but
the problem is the modify will not work immediately untill I open the system settings app again .
I guess the value change is not notify to system in my app.

Comment: Please add your current code.

Comment: Settings.Global changes are explicitly done by system UI. Are you working on eng binary device ?

Comment: @Vinodh     I use nexus 6, userdebug mode .    and I want my app to change the value ,not through system UI.

Comment: How are you adding app to /system/app ? Is your device rooted ?

Comment: @Vinodh I use nexus 6, userdebug mode . and I want my app to change the value ,not through system UI.

Comment: @Vinodh   the device has tooted, and I  use systemappmover to convert my app to system app .